# Is it OK to define operator<< or operator>> for FILE&?

Tags: c++, c, operator-overloading, language-lawyer

This may sound like a strange question, but am I safe in defining `operator<<` or `operator>>` for a `FILE` object, or would I be violating potential clauses in the C or C++ standards, or can it possibly cause other issues?

(Yes, I **do** know about C++ I/O streams. I'm **not** asking if this is a *good* idea. I'm asking if it's *allowed*.)

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE &operator>>(FILE &file, int &d)
{
    if (fread(&d, sizeof(d), 1, &file) != 1)
    { throw "I/O error"; }
    return file;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    FILE *file = fopen("File.bin", "rb");
    *file >> x;
    fclose(file);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: I would argue this has nothing to do with C.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Is `FILE` even mentioned in the C++ standard?

Comment: I'm not sure. But I'm sure that the C standard doesn't have a `<cstdio>`. Perhaps the C++ spec defers to the C spec here?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: The C standard has an `stdio.h`, which I in fact referenced. I think the C++ standard does defer to C here.

Comment: I think it would not have any problem, but like you said, it's strange.

Comment: Playing in the middle of the freeway is __allowed__... it's not a __good__ idea though.  Try it! (overloading operators for FILE, not _playing in the street_.)  It's your code!  Won't break anything!

Comment: @lornix: I actually think that playing in the middle of the freeway might be illegal in some places. =P

Comment: @so61pi: Feel free to post it as an answer if you're fairly confident!

Comment: For all we know, `FILE` could be a typedef for `struct __real_file*`.

Comment: @n.m.: Would that pose a problem?

Comment: I think this should be valid as long as the C standard requires that `FILE*` is always dereferencable. For instance, if it's an opaque pointer whose definition is not visible, the code will not compile. You'll also need to take care you never make a copy of the dereferenced `FILE` object.

Comment: Yes, it's not class or enumerated type. You can only overload on one of these kinds.

Comment: @Praetorian The C standard does not require FILE to be a complete type. The code will compile even if it is not.

Comment: @n.m.: Oops! I didn't realize that. Could you please post that as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @n.m. He's dereferencing it here - `*file >> x;`

Comment: @Praetorian: That doesn't require it to be a complete type, does it? It's converted to a reference, not a value.

Comment: @Mehrdad You're right, missed that you're binding it to a reference

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ignoring, for the moment, the question of whether this is a good idea (but it's not), it's open to question whether this is truly allowed.

The C++ standard defines all the relevant headers and functions--`<cstdio>` is covered in §27.9.2. If you really wanted to use it, `<stdio.h>` is even part of the C++ standard (§D.5), though it's officially deprecated.

That would tend to indicate that it's allowed. The wording from the C standard (§7.19.1/2) is:

> ```
>         FILE
> ```
>
> which is an object type capable of recording all the information needed to control a
>   stream, including its file position indicator, a pointer to its associated buffer (if any), an error indicator that records whether a read/write error has occurred, and an end-of-file
>   indicator that records whether the end of the file has been reached;

The question would be whether a `FILE` is really required to represent that type directly, or could (for example) be `typedef`d to `void`, so (for example) `fopen` actually returns a `void *`. The internals of the library that use it would cast it to the proper type, but to the outside world (i.e., your program) it's completely opaque. In particular, if it is a `void *`, you can't dereference it, not even to just get a reference instead of a pointer.

I'd guess that's mostly theoretical though. I think in general, assuming that `FILE` is a unique type on which you can do overloading is fairly safe. You shouldn't assume anything about the internals of what it points at, but you're fairly safe assuming you can  dereference it to get a reference instead of a pointer (and fairly safe assuming that the overload will be differentiated from overloads on other types such as integers).

Comment: No, `void` is not an object type, but e.g. `char[128]` is, and `struct __real_file*` is too. If your impl has 1024 bit int, then `int1024_t` also qualifies. You cannot overload on either.

Comment: @n.m. You should be able to overload on `struct __real_file*`.  The real issue is `int1014_t`.

Comment: You could always create a thin type wrapper on which you use your operator overloads which in turn will directly act on the FILE* with the standard API.